# Execute command inside if

Tags: vimscript

I use `fzf.vim` plugin and I want to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>:

1. If the file is part of a git repo, then I want to use the `:GFiles` command (to show all files from the root directory of project).
2. If there is no git repo, then I want to use `:Files` (to show files from the directory that contains the file).

I wrote this function. It executes `git status` and check if it succeeded; if so, it's a git repo, otherwise not.

```
function! MyFunc()
    " echo 'MyFunc() begin'
    let status = system("git status")
    if v:shell_error
        echo 'v:shell_error cmd'
        execute "normal! :Files<CR>"
    else
        echo 'else cmd'
        execute "normal! :GFiles<CR>"
    endif
    " echo 'MyFunc() end'
endfunction
```

However, it doesn't work, the function gets called, but the if and else statements are omitted.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but `execute "normal! :Files<CR>"` can just be `Files` (and similarly for `GFiles`). Have you tried `:debug call MyFunc()`?

Comment: Change code to simply Files and GFiles and not it works! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe could you accept you own answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I don't know is it ok ? Because answer is my, but solution is not.

Comment: The accept button is to indicate others that the solution provided solved your problem. It is a good indication that if you have the same problem you should look at that solution first ;-). In short yes feel free to accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks D.Ben Knoble for help. Full code

```
function! MyFunc()
    let status = system("git status")
    if v:shell_error
        Files
    else
        GFiles
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Hm, perhaps you needed either `:execute 'normal! :Files<CR>'` (single quotes) or `:execute "normal! :Files\<CR>"` (escaped key-sequence in double-quotes).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Your first suggestion won't work as <key> notation is only expanded by `:map` or such. Neither execute nor normal do this. The second one will, because backslash inside double quotes allows for substs"

Comment: @Matt yes, I think you are right, thanks for reminding me. One more reason to keep it simple with just the command :)